# Command stored on a variable runs when script is executed

Tags: bash

I have this variable, which is used as value in multiple conditions among the script:
`test=$(find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.mkv"  -o -name "*.mp4" | wc -l)`

The conditions are like:
`if [ "$test" -ge 1 ];`

However, everytime I execute the script, the variable runs the find command, even though it was not called yet.

Is there a way to store that command to be ran only when needed?

Thanks!

Comment: `find` is invoked when `test` is assigned, not when `test` is referenced.  You could write a function that caches the result of `find` and call that function instead of referencing a variable when you do the check.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: @AndréLuís, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `check_count() { if test -z "$file_count"; then file_count=$( find ...); fi; test "$file_count" -gt "${1-1}"; }`

Comment: BTW, the reason I added the duplicate asking about memoizing results is that if you want your function to both be evaluated only when the value is wanted, but *not* be evaluated more than once, "memoization" is the technique you want to use to cache that result.